# WooCommerce error "invalid recurring shipping method" when combining subscription and one-time purchase

Tags: woocommerce, error-handling, plugins, woocommerce-subscriptions, shipping-method

In WooCommerce, I am receiving the Error "Invalid Recurring Shipping Method" at checkout when the cart includes BOTH a subscription product and a One Time Purchase Product.

Here is the current set-up and scenario. On my landing page, I have three offers for a product:

1. Single Product
2. Subscription Product Option
3. Buy 3 Get 1 Free Offer

Customer Chooses Options > Checkout Page

On Checkout page, there is a Cart upsell offer (Buy 2 for 50% OFF Offer).

> **The Error happens when I have added the Subscription Product AND then add the Buy 2 for 50% Offer)**

**Shipping Criteria:**
Free Shipping for Subscription Product OR if cart is $50 or More

**Plugin Setup**

- WooCommerce - Free Shipping option created & Flat Rate ($6) Option created
- WooCommerce Subscriptions - Latest version 5.1.3 "Allow multiple subscriptions and products to be purchased simultaneously." - Enabled
- Conditional Shipping For WooCommerce:

  - **Rule 1**
    If Subscription Product X is in Cart OR subtotal >= $50
    Then
    Enable Free shipping and Disable Standard Shipping
  - **Rule 2**    -
    If Subtotal < $50 
    Then
    Enable Express Shipping
    Disable Free Shipping.

With all these settings. I get the error note above...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any thoughts?

I tried disabling the plugins Conditional Shipping plugin, but it still gave me the same error. Disabling it just showed me two different shipping rates, Free & Flat Fee Rate.